# value replacement not allowed not working Angular - regex

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I have a regular expression that allows only letters inside a text field, it works fine when writing something in the field, but when the user pastes a string with characters not allowed I have to do a cleanup, and for that I'm using the same expression original with the "replace" method but it doesn't work for me and it doesn't do the replacement when the characters don't match.

The REGEX: /^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ., ]*$/;

Works with directive:

[image]

after to paste i need to replace unsupported values ​​using the same expression but it doesn't work

```
onPasteCustom($event: any) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    let text = $event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'); //works
    const cleanText = text.replace(/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ., ]*$/, ''); //not work, not replace
    this.form.controls['detail'].setValue(cleanText);
}
```

Why as a directive if the regex works for me but using the replace does not behave the same?

Comment: What do you seen when you do `console.log(text);` ?

Comment: Before doing the replace, I see the same text that is entered in the text box and after doing the replace, I still see the same thing

Comment: you probably want replaceAll() or add "/g" to regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex requires *every* character in the input to be in the character class (because it is anchored with `^` and `$`) to do a replacement. As soon as one character is not in the class, there will be no replacement done at all. What you want is to just match a single character in the class and replace that, using the `g` flag to replace all occurrences.

```js
texts = ['Random String', 'Random String!']
regexs = [/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ., ]*$/, /[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ., ]/g]

for (let regex of regexs) {
  console.log(`Replacing using regex ${regex}`)
  for (let text of texts) {
    console.log(`"${text}" => "${text.replace(regex, '')}"`)
  }
}
```

Note it seems that you might actually want the inverted character class?

```js
texts = ['Random String', 'Random String!']
regexs = [/^[^a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ., ]*$/, /[^a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ., ]/g]

for (let regex of regexs) {
  console.log(`Replacing using regex ${regex}`)
  for (let text of texts) {
    console.log(`"${text}" => "${text.replace(regex, '')}"`)
  }
}
```